# Is it possible to display a Twitter Bootstrap Progress bar while the browser downloads the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site with lots of large images and I'd like to display a twitter bootstrap progress bar while everything is loading.

Is it possible to do this? Does jquery have a way of tracking the progress of a page loading?

I'd like to display just a progress bar until all the css, js, and images, etc. have be downloaded.

Comment: You want to display a progress bar for the "HTTP page request"?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a way of tracking the progress, however, you could use an indeterminate progress bar (similar to a spinner).

Comment: Not the way you are planning on doing it.

Comment: Thanks. That helps point me in the right direction. Have other people solved this problem another way? Would you just display the spinner until document ready?

Comment: well, document ready happens before all the images are loaded. I'd suggest showing it until window load.

Comment: I guess this is the sort of thing that I was looking for. I suppose you could tweak it to work with Bootstrap: http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="imagelist">
    <img src="http://studio7designs.com/wp-content/uploads/green-grass.jpeg"/>
    <img src="http://studio7designs.com/wp-content/uploads/rowboat-600x398.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://studio7designs.com/wp-content/uploads/blue-wheat-grass.jpeg"/>
    <img src="http://studio7designs.com/wp-content/uploads/rocks.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://studio7designs.com/wp-content/uploads/sun-grass-golden.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://studio7designs.com/wp-content/uploads/blue-water-photo.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://studio7designs.com/wp-content/uploads/flight.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$.fn.imagesLoaded = function (callback, onEach) {
    var elems = this.filter('img'),
        len = elems.length,
        blank = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";

    elems.bind('load.imgloaded', function () {
        if(typeof onEach === 'function'){
            onEach(len, elems.length); // runs on every image load
        }

        if (--len <= 0 && this.src !== blank) {
            elems.unbind('load.imgloaded');
            callback.call(elems, this);
        }
    }).each(function () {
        // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src.
        if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined) {
            var src = this.src;
            // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
            // data uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
            this.src = blank;
            this.src = src;
        }
    });

    return this;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var progress = $('.progress');
    var progressbar = progress.children('.bar');

    $('.imagelist img').imagesLoaded(function () {
        progressbar.width('100%');
        progress.fadeOut();
    }, function (left, total) {
        progressbar.width((total - left) / total * 100 + '%');
    });
});
```

I took the .imagesLoaded() code written by Paul Irish, and added an additional callback that's triggered every time an image is loaded. So for every image that's loaded, the progress bar progresses.

It's not entirely accurate because it doesn't track how much of any particular file is loaded, and I'm not entirely sure that's possible without complicating this code, so the progress bar only changes when an image is loaded rather than while it's loading.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, you don't need to track how much of the file is loaded. You could make it look like it does with .animate().